# Datetime and SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = TODAY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, pdo

The column (date) in the database says "2013-10-14 14:37:38" for example.

How can I edit `$todaysDate` to display ALL dates today? I know that I have to use % somewhere but I have tried a lot of ways without success. :/

My code is below:

```
$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d");

$query_today = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date=:date");
$query_today->bindParam(":date", $todaysDate);
$query_today->execute();
```

**UPDATE**
Nothing below is working. I just want to select all dates in the database from a simple `date("Y-m-d")`. If the date is "2013-10-14 14:37:38" in the database I want to select it with just 2013-10-14. Something like `date("Y-m-d%")`.

Comment: Does DATE(date_field) not return the date without the time in MySQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example, if you will search other dates beside today:

```
$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d"); # or any other date
$query_today = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(date) = :date");
$query_today->bindParam(":date", $todaysDate);
$query_today->execute();
```

Example, only for current date:

```
$query_today = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()");
$query_today->execute();
```

---

p.s. but like [@ypercube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19361162/67332) said, if you have index on date field, his example will use that index.

```
$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d");
$query_today = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= :date AND date < DATE_ADD(:date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
$query_today->bindParam(":date", $todaysDate);
$query_today->execute();
```

or

```
$query_today = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= CURDATE() AND date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
$query_today->execute();
```

Comment: Didn't quite understand that part with index. Do you want to explain it?

Answer (score 5):

This will work whether the column is of type `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` and will use an index, if there is one available:

```
WHERE date >= CURRENT_DATE
  AND date < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: OP wants to get the record of current date only not of next date.

Answer (score 2):

A simple

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = DATE(NOW())
```

should suffice.

Or as Alma pointed out,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = CURDATE()
```

Comment: Why do this? Discover `CURDATE()`

Comment: Does work.. Do I have to do something with the variable (`$todaysDate`)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of below code:

```
$query_today = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date=:date");
```

Use the following code:

```
$query_today = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')=:date");
```

Comment: This will not use any index and will scan the whole table.

Comment: @ypercube use has define in the code that he/she is using the current date `$query_today->bindParam(":date", $todaysDate)` may be you don't have idea about PDO. This the method to bind the parameters value in PDO.

Comment: I'm talking about the `DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-%d', date)` part. This will invalidate the use of any index.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any correction towards allowing index use. You only corrected the syntax.

Comment: @ypercube other things are correct see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Any idea why it still doesn't work? If I put "2013-10-14 14:37:38" in `$todaysDate` I will have one result. But I want all results of todays date.

Answer (score -1):

`$query_today = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(date)=DATE(:date)");`